# What do the three groups of girls represent?

Tags: riddle

There are three groups of girls.

- The first group *(three girls)* has naturally straight hair.
- The second group *(four girls)* used a curler, some missed a few strands that remains straight.
- The third group *(three girls)* has naturally curly hair.

You look at them regularly. What do the three groups of girls represent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think these are

> the digits 0-9.

The first group

> consists of digits 147, made out of straight lines.

The second group

> consists of digits 2359, made out of some straight lines and some curves. (There are different ways of forming the digits, and some ways of writing 3 and 9 are all-curves.)

The third group

> consists of digits 068, made out of curves only. (Some ways of writing 6 are a mixture of curves and straight lines.)

I am a little uneasy

> about the asymmetry between 6 and 9 here, though I think it's fairly common to handwrite a 9 as a circle with a vertical line descending from it, and much less common to do an equivalent thing with 6. There's some ambiguity about 3, too.